# What does convolving an image with kernel [1 -2 1] do? How is it different than convolving with the derivative kernel [1 -1]?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

What does convolving an image with the filter [1 -2 1] do? I see that it's a form of edge detection but it's also very similar to the results I get when convolving with the derivative kernel [1 -1] so I don't really see the difference between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are high pass filters. Filtering with [1 -2 1] is the same as filtering with [1 -1] twice. So the longer kernel is a steeper high pass filter and emphasize the edges more.

Comment: As mentioned by @Cris below, it's not general highpass filter, but is a discrete-time differentiator (first derivative or slope) and two differentiators (second derivative or curvature).

Answer (score 6):

Convolution with the `[1 -1]` kernel (A) is a derivative filter, which computes the finite difference approximation to the first derivative.

The `[1 -2 1]` kernel (B) is the result of convolving kernel A with itself. Thus, convolving an image with kernel A twice is the same as convolving with kernel B once. This means that convolution with kernel B is a second derivative filter, and computes the finite difference approximation to the second derivative.